# Detect and Run Service if not running

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

How to Detect if service is not running and run the service again in every after 5 Sec

```
 try {


        Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, OnlineWatcherService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),5000, pintent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service Alaram", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For detect is running your service or not you can use following method:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then

```
  if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)) //do something here
```